# Box model sizing on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css

I have the following code, that shows what I want in Chrome, but in Firefox, the `width` attributes on the `panel` divs are not obeyed.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ltsaj

Comment: Why are you using the old [flexbox implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox#box-_implementation) and not the more [current one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox#flex-_implementation)?

Comment: Because, as that page says: 
This newer specification will not work in current versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues with Firefox currently. Firstly, you have to use the old wording (i.e. `display: -moz-flexbox;`). And secondly, Firefox has a known bug to do with specifying widths as percentages: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=529761

An alternate solution might be to consider using `display: inline-block;` to achieve what you are after. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/QbZrH/

Comment: Alright, so considering the long-standing bug, what's the best way to get it to work on Firefox as well?

Comment: I haven't used flexbox yet do to the amount of bugs. I would recommend using `display: inline-block;` for layouts at the moment. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/QbZrH/

Comment: Also, if you want a bit more information on `display: inline-block;` I wrote this article recently: http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

Comment: If you needed the heights to be the same, then you could also consider using `display: table-cell;` (as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/KXYRm/). This also has pretty reasonable browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=display:%20table